# How to overwrite ruby method's local variable while writing rspec test cases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Existing Ruby Code:

```
def book_details
  book_count = Book.count
  while (book_count > 1)
    # Do something
  end
end
```

I want to write rspec test case which sets the book_count value in the book_details function. Is it possible? If yes, how?

So far, what I have tried is:

```
it 'Should return 1 book details only' do
  allow(Model).to receive(book_count).and_return(1)
  # Do something
end
```

But this is giving error 'undefined local variable or method `book_count' for #

Comment: Try `allow(Book).to receive(:count).and_return(1)`.

Comment: If you find yourself testing internals of the implementation (including, but not limited to: private functions, local variables, etc,) you are doing it wrong and you have to review the whole design. Here I believe the proper tests would be: 1. Create a _single_ `Book` instance, test. 2. Create two `Book` instances, test.

Comment: Thanks @ndn - It works like a gem.

Comment: But for this case its fine. Is there anyway to set a local variable? Lets say book_count = 1000 was there in a ruby code. I want to reset it as 10 with rspec.

Comment: No you can't set a local variable being used in model from a RSpec.

Comment: @Sk.Irfan in addition to `ndn`'s answer, it'd be safer to use `allow(Book).to receive(:count).once.and_return(1)`, as you are expecting it to be called only once, otherwise perhaps somewhere along the line `Book.count` has been called more than once in that specific test execution, and you do not want to accidentally override the value of `Book.count` in the other ones.

Comment: It actually is *possible* to change local variables "from a distance" in ruby, but - trust me when I say this - that's *NOT* what you should be doing!! (Ever!!) For details on the black magic by which this is possible, see: https://aphyr.com/posts/173-monkeypatching-is-for-wimps-use-set-trace-func

Answer (score 0):

Lets say book_count = 1000 was there in a ruby code and you want to reset it as 10 with rspec, then below is okay:

```
allow(Book).to receive(:count).and_return(10)
```

Above will give a count as per your expectation in rspec.

Also, be specific with your `rspec contexts`, `rspec` is written for `methods`, not for `local variables`. 
So, test method expectations in `rspec`.

Below is the simple `rspec` example for your `method`:

```
class Book

  def book_details
    book_count = Book.count
    while (book_count > 1)
      puts 'Book name'
    end
  end

end

describe 'Books' do

  describe '#book_details' do

    context 'when Books are less than one' do

      it 'should not return book details' do
        book_details.should eq 0
        book_details.should_not eq 'Book name'
      end

    end

    context 'when Books are more than one' do

      before do
        FactoryGirl.create(:book)
      end

      it 'should return book details' do
        book_details.should_not eq 0
        book_details.should eq 'Book name'
      end

    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, basically, is: Don't.

If you feel the need to override variables in the middle of a method, you're doing it wrong; the method has too many responsibilities and needs to be broken up.

In your case here, the one quick way to get the test working would be:

```
allow(Book).to receive(:count).once.and_return(1)
```

Or, a slightly cleaner approach would be to extract that call into a new method, so you're only stubbing behaviour that you "own" - something like:

```
class Foo
  def book_details
    while (book_count > 1)
      # Do something
    end
  end

  def book_count
    Book.count
  end
end

# In your test:
let(:foo) { Foo.new }
allow(foo).to receive(:book_count).once.and_return(1)
```

...But in fact, what you should *really* be doing here, ideally, to test the method properly, would be to not mock anything at all! Since your code is interacting with the database, your tests should create real records for the code to interact with:

```
# Using FactoryBot, for example:
let!(:books) { create_list(:book, 5) }
```

Comment: I have a case where, in a method I have variables saying limit = 25, In the test cases, I need only 1. So, I need to set the limit as 1.

Comment: Don't do it as a simple variable, then. That sounds to me like you should be using a config value, that varies depending on your Rails environment. The basic idea is: `book_count = Rails.env.test? 1 : 25` -- only you don't want to litter the code base with all these conditionals, so you should refactor that into something along the lines of: `book_count = CONFIG_VALUES.fetch(:book_count, 25)`.

Comment: There are many ways to implement such a "config file" (for example, maybe it needs to be an isolated service, for changing across multiple servers at runtime??). For example, [this gem](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) provides a fairly simple implementation.

Comment: Or like I originally suggested, if this override is only needed in **some** tests, then this would be a valid use case for mocking a method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Book.stub(:count).and_return(10)
```